# Phaser 3 arcade physics world wraparound

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make an Asteroids game in Phaser 3 (javascript) using the Arcade Physics engine.

I want the effect where objects that leave one side of the screen come back from the opposite side.

The API documentation describes a function [here](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World.html#wrap) that allows you to "Wrap an object's coordinates (or several objects' coordinates) within Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World#bounds."

I am having trouble implementing it. I have a group for the asteroids called asteroids. Currently my implementation is `this.physics.world.wrap(asteroids);` however this does not get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was just calling in the wrong place-- I moved the call from the create function to the update function and everything worked!